# Java: BufferedReader and WebAPI response

Tags: java, json, asp.net-web-api, bufferedreader

I have a bufferedReader that is accepting response from a WebAPI for an httpPost request.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

 /* send http-POST request to webAPI */
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(input.getBytes());
os.flush();


BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));
```

The data contained in 'br' as a result of a httpPost request made to the webapi:-

```
{
   "xx" : "...."
   "yy" : "...."
   "zz" : "...."
}
HTTP/1.1 202... blah blah blah
Content-Length: 35
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Connection: close
```

First of all I would like to point out that it is weird that I am getting header information in the response itself...but only for JAVA.. ( I code the same thing with C#, which is where I am most proficient and didn't receive any header information back). Is this even possible? since... in my understanding, what the webapi responds is independent of C# or Java code?

Now my main objective is to extract the value for the key 'zz'.

I was trying something like:-

```
 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
  try
   {
     JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(br);
   }
  catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e)
   {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

However because of the weird HTTP/202 response part of the message, I am getting an error "Unexpected character (H) at position 281".

So, I am thinking, maybe I need to truncate my buffer 'br' before I try to use JSON. I am wondering what is the best way of doing this?

Comment: you're getting that error because the string that you're parsing is not valid `JSON`

Comment: I do understand that Raman. However in my next statement I mention how I am trying to figure out how to truncate that string so I can parse it as json.

Comment: ya as you said in question, you can truncate it as well. But why are you making it complex. Why not use something simple like Regular Expressions? See this link https://regex101.com/r/gN4oJ8/2. See the Match information column on the RHS

Comment: nice, didnt think about that approach. Also, it is weird that my response contains header information... dont you think? for my C# code, the response from the webapi doesn't contain any header information... only for my java code do I get that stuff included... any ideas?

Comment: I also do deal with response data and there is usually header information appended to it. The thing is that whatever response data is returned by the server is enclosed is `data` key of json automatically.

Comment: Use a tool like Postman (chrome extension) and try to send a mirrored request to that service again. See what actual response you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it through `json` will make it more complex because you'd have first convert it into proper `json` in order to allow `json` parser to parse.

A more optimal way to do it would be through Regular Expressions

**Input**

```
{
   xx : 
   yy :
   zz : sample 123123
}
HTTP/1.1 202... blah blah blah
Content-Length: 35
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Connection: close
```

**Regular Expression**

```
.*zz\s*:\s*(.*)[\n\r]/g
```

**Output**

```
sample 123123
```

See [this link](https://regex101.com/r/gN4oJ8/2) for more details